Reactgrid: Focus is not shifting when we click outside the @silevis/reactgrid
Referring to https://reactgrid.com/examples, in the examples, if we click outside the table, the focus still persists on the cell.
Want to implement the feature, which will cancel the highlight once click outside the cell
